# how to get hourly data from database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I  have to get the data from database hourly base  on datetime ,I tried it but not able to get that idea ..I am new to sql can you help me please. I am trying get data for particular user in an hour how many actions does he performed

```
select username,count(message) as '8-9',count(message) as '9-10',count(message) as '10-11'
from customer_1.audit_trail 
inner join inteliviz.user on customer_1.audit_trail.user_id = inteliviz.users.id 
where datetime>'2013-08-21 08:00:00' and datetime<'2013-08-21 09:00:00'
group by username  limit 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Between**

```
select username,count(message) as '8-9',count(message) as '9-10',count(message) as '10-11'
from customer_1.audit_trail 
inner join inteliviz.user on customer_1.audit_trail.user_id = inteliviz.users.id 
where datetime between '2013-08-21 08:00:00' and '2013-08-21 09:00:00'
group by username  limit 1000;
```

Comment: where datetime between '2013-08-21 08:00:00' and '2013-08-21 09:00:00'

Comment: where datetime between '2013-08-21 08:00:00' and '2013-08-21 09:00:00' where datetime between '2013-08-21 09:00:00' and '2013-08-21 10:00:00' I want to the date to reteived every hour where it displays the count(messages) as 9-10,10-11

Comment: username        8-9    9-10   10-11                                                   aftabh         12 12 12
morrisonsts 13 13 13
richardt 15 15 15

Comment: sorry for not providing accurate table data not able to get that.. but i get that acquired for 8-9 i want it display it for 9-10,10-11

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining clearly I get the count of  data for particular user in between 8-9 its good sofar but need to get that every hour.. its like that I   should use multiple where statments ...how can i have multiple where statments based on dateime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35907/discussion-between-upvote-markanswer-and-kiran-v)